# What should I add more to retrieve full reputation points in SEDE?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Using [this option](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1160851/how-to-receive-detailed-reputation-from-sede?UserId=1719510):

```
;with postvotes as
(
select v.creationdate
     , p.id postid
     , case v.votetypeid
       when  1 then 'accepts'
       when 2 then 'up-votes'
       when 3 then 'down-votes'
       when 9 then 'bounty_recieved'
       end  vote_type
     , case p.posttypeid
       when 1 then 'question'
       when 2 then 'answer'
       end post_type
     , sum(case  v.votetypeid
           when 1 then 15
           when 2 then 10
           when 3 then -2
           when 9 then bountyamount
           end
       ) reputation_change

from votes v
inner join posts p on p.id = v.postid
where p.owneruserid = ##userid?1719510##
and posttypeid in (1,2)
and votetypeid in (1,2,3,9)
group by v.creationdate, p.id, votetypeid, posttypeid
),
bounties as
(
select v.creationdate
     , v.postid postid
     , 'bounty-offered' vote_type
     , 'question' post_type
     , sum(bountyamount) reputation_change
from votes v
where v.userid = ##userid?1719510##
and votetypeid = 8
group by v.creationdate, v.postid, votetypeid
),
approvededits as
(
select se.creationdate
     , se.postid postid
     , 'approved-edit' vote_type
     , case p.posttypeid
       when 1 then 'question'
       when 2 then 'answer'
       end  post_type
     , sum(2) reputation_change
from suggestededits se
inner join posts p on p.id = se.postid
where se.Owneruserid = ##userid?1719510##
and approvaldate is not null
group by se.creationdate, se.postid, posttypeid
)


select *
from postvotes
union
select *
from bounties
union
select *
from approvededits
```

What should be added to receive the full detailed reputation?

Comment: What does it return now?

Comment: SEDE is refresh once a week. It's up to date only for a really limited amount of time.

Comment: This is not a sensible use-case for SEDE. Why not just query the API?

Comment: Isn't there a convention of using uppercase for SQL keywords?

Answer (score 8):

Getting a fully accurate reputation number via SEDE is not possible. There are events that affect your reputation but do not show up in SEDE, such as:

1. -1 from downvoting answers
2. +1 from removing your downvote on an answer, or if that answer is deleted
3. -2 when a post you have an accepted suggested edit on is deleted
4. -100 when a post of yours is red-flag deleted
5. Legacy reputation retained when documentation shut down
6. Reputation from deleted posts that is retained (Score >3, Visibility >60 Days, thanks Erik A's answer)

That being said, some time ago I wrote a query that calculates any user's reputation up to a certain date (use today for current) with a breakdown. It can be found [on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/882556/reputation-gained-until-a-certain-date):

```
SELECT
-- Total Reputation
(
SUM(CASE WHEN r2d.ReputationFromVotes + r2d.ReputationFromSuggestedEdits > 200 THEN 200 ELSE r2d.ReputationFromVotes + r2d.ReputationFromSuggestedEdits END) 
+ SUM(r2d.ReputationFromBounties) 
+ COALESCE((SELECT SUM(v4.BountyAmount * -1) FROM Votes AS v4 WHERE v4.VoteTypeId = 8 AND v4.UserId = ##UserId## AND v4.CreationDate < ##UntilDate:string## ),0)
+ COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) * 2 FROM Posts AS p3 WHERE p3.OwnerUserId = ##UserId## AND p3.AcceptedAnswerId IS NOT NULL),0)
+ SUM(r2d.ReputationFromAccepts)
) AS TotalReputation,
-- Rep Capped Activities with the Cap Factored in
SUM(
CASE 
WHEN r2d.ReputationFromVotes + r2d.ReputationFromSuggestedEdits > 200 THEN 200
ELSE r2d.ReputationFromVotes + r2d.ReputationFromSuggestedEdits 
END) AS ReputationFromRepCap,
-- Total Bounties recieved
SUM(r2d.ReputationFromBounties) AS ReputationFromBounties,
-- Total Bounties given
COALESCE((SELECT SUM(v4.BountyAmount * -1) FROM Votes AS v4 WHERE v4.VoteTypeId = 8 AND v4.UserId = ##UserId## AND v4.CreationDate < ##UntilDate:string## ),0) AS ReputationGivenAsBounties,
-- Total Reputation from Accepting Answers
COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) * 2 FROM Posts AS p3 WHERE p3.OwnerUserId = ##UserId## AND p3.AcceptedAnswerId IS NOT NULL),0) AS ReputationFromAcceptingAnswers,
-- Total Reputation from Accepted Answers
SUM(r2d.ReputationFromAccepts) AS ReputationFromAcceptedAnswers


FROM

(

SELECT 
v.CreationDate AS VoteDate,

-- Total Reputation from Post Upvotes
-- PostTypeId 1 = Question, 2 = Answer
-- VoteTypeId 2 = Upvote, 3 = Downvote
-- CommunityOwnedDate is when a post was made CW. 
-- Votes before that count, after not.
-- Vote Date is truncated to full days only so grouping works
SUM((CASE 
  WHEN (p.PostTypeId = 1 AND v.VoteTypeId = 2 AND (p.CommunityOwnedDate > v.CreationDate OR p.CommunityOwnedDate IS NULL)) THEN 10 
  WHEN (p.PostTypeId = 2 AND v.VoteTypeId = 2 AND (p.CommunityOwnedDate > v.CreationDate OR p.CommunityOwnedDate IS NULL)) THEN 10 
  WHEN (v.VoteTypeId = 3 AND (p.CommunityOwnedDate > v.CreationDate OR p.CommunityOwnedDate IS NULL)) THEN -2
  ELSE 0 
END)) AS ReputationFromVotes,

-- Total Reputation from Answer Bounties
-- VoteTypeId 9 = Bounty Close (Bounty Awarded)
-- BountyAmount = Amount of Reputation awarded
SUM(CASE 
  WHEN v.VoteTypeId = 9 THEN v.BountyAmount
  ELSE 0
END) AS ReputationFromBounties,

-- Total Reputation from Answer Accepts
-- VoteTypeId 1 = AcceptedByOriginator (Answer Accepted)
SUM(CASE
  WHEN (v.VoteTypeId = 1 AND (p.CommunityOwnedDate > v.CreationDate OR p.CommunityOwnedDate IS NULL)) THEN 15
  ELSE 0 
END) AS ReputationFromAccepts,

-- Total Reputation from Suggested Edits
-- if ApprovalDate isn't NULL and RejectionDate is NULL it's been approved and not overriden
-- Group by the same Date as Votes for Rep-Cap evaluation (They count towards it)
COALESCE((SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN (se.ApprovalDate IS NOT NULL AND se.RejectionDate IS NULL) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END)
FROM SuggestedEdits AS se
WHERE se.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
AND YEAR(v.CreationDate) = YEAR(se.ApprovalDate)
AND MONTH(v.CreationDate) = MONTH(se.ApprovalDate)
AND DAY(v.CreationDate) = DAY(se.ApprovalDate) ),0) AS ReputationFromSuggestedEdits

FROM Posts AS p 
INNER JOIN Votes AS v ON v.PostId = p.Id

WHERE p.OwnerUserId =  ##UserId:int##
AND v.CreationDate <= ##UntilDate:string##

GROUP BY v.CreationDate

) as r2d
```

This query attempts to take into account the rep cap and as many other factors as possible, but it is not fully accurate due to the limitations mentioned above.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something one small improvement to that would be to not count the +15 for an accepted answer if it was a self-answered question.

Comment: @PeterJ thats true, it doesn't count those cases. I might take another pass at this later to fix some more stuff, I just dug it out after remembering I wrote something like that once.

Comment: If you're going to rework it, you might want to exclude the _accepted edits by deleted users_ too.

Answer (score 4):

You can't calculate full reputation using SEDE.

Things that are missing because of anonymization:

- Downvotes you cast on answers (subtract 1 rep)
- Spam flag penalties against your posts (subtract 100 rep)
- Deleted posts that stayed around long enough not to revert reputation (score > 3 and visibility for >60 days).

Things that are hard to account for:

- Lower rep boundary (you can't have less than 1 rep, so some downvotes don't count)
- Reputation limit per day earned out of votes/edits (200)

Things that are often forgotten:

- Edits approved by deleted users (these have no effect on rep)
- Accepted answers on questions by the same user
- Community wiki questions and answers

You missed all of the items in *Things that are often forgotten* and *things that are hard to account for*, plus obviously all items out of *things that are missing because of anonymization* because these are always missing